# Spring rest controller returns 404

Tags: spring, rest

My rest controller ,which is written by spring, returns 404 but when I debug over Eclipse , I see that it comes to my method and returns result but result is still 404.

Controller is like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("admin/context")
public class ApplicationAdmin {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContextService applicationContextService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/monitor",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Response monitorContexts(){
        return this.applicationContextService.monitorContext();
    }
}
```

There is no exception or error. And the request ur is:

http://localhost:8080/appl_war/admin/context/monitor

Comment: it is not able to find the controller. What is cmsgateway? shouldn't the url be http://localhost:8080/appl_war/admin/context/monitor  ??

Comment: show your DispatcherServlet configuration in web.xml. Check your <url-pattern> value, if you have **<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>** then your URL should be http://localhost:8080/appl_war/admin/context/monitor

Comment: Edited url. there is no cmsgateway. The requests come to my controller method, I can see that. But it still gives 404...

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

make sure your configuration contains **@EnableWebMvc**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"bla.bla.bla"})
    public class Configuration{
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Danyal Sandeelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1230257/danyal-sandeelo) says, I think you have to change the `RequestMapping` value at class level from *"admin/context"* to "*cmsgateway/admin/context*".

Comment: Edited url. there is no cmsgateway. The requests come to my controller method, I can see that. But it still gives 404...

Comment: Arrg! I missed that too! Try this, "/admin/context" (note that it starts with /)