# Spring returns 404 when using MethodValidationPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with my test Spring Boot app. It works just fine, but when I enable Spring validation by adding dependency etc and adding a `@Configuration`:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
  }
}
```

I get 404 for my test endpoint.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1601507037178,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/test"
}
```

I've already applied some solutions/proposals from similar problems (eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983699/spring-rest-controller-returns-404) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594623/spring-rest-controller-requestparam-validation)) but without a success.

Here is my code:
https://github.com/zolv/error-handling-test

API interface:

```
@Validated
public interface TestApi {

  @PostMapping(
      value = "/test",
      produces = {"application/json"},
      consumes = {"application/json"})
  @ResponseBody
  ResponseEntity<TestEntity> getTest(@Valid @RequestBody(required = false) TestEntity request);
}
```

`TestEntity` just to send something:

```
@Data
public class TestEntity {
  @JsonProperty("test")
  @NotNull
  private String test;
}
```

Controller implementation:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
public class TestController implements TestApi {
  @Override
  @ResponseBody
  public ResponseEntity<TestEntity> getTest(@Valid @RequestBody TestEntity request) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(request);
  }
}
```

My controller advice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class DefaultErrorHandlerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(value = {ConstraintViolationException.class})
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  @ResponseBody
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleValidationFailure(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
    StringBuilder messages = new StringBuilder();

    for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : ex.getConstraintViolations()) {
      messages.append(violation.getMessage());
    }

    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(messages.toString());
  }

  @Override
  @ResponseBody
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
      MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
      HttpHeaders headers,
      HttpStatus status,
      WebRequest request) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PROBLEM_JSON)
        .body("problem");
  }
}
```

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test")
public class TestApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

A test I use, but it fails also using Postman:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class TestControllerTest {

  @Autowired protected TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Test
  void registrationHappyPath() throws Exception {
    /*
     * Given
     */
    final TestEntity request = new TestEntity();

    /*
     * When/
     */
    final ResponseEntity<String> response =
        restTemplate.postForEntity("/test", request, String.class);

    /*
     * Then
     */
    Assertions.assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, response.getStatusCode());

    final String body = response.getBody();
    Assertions.assertNotNull(body);
  }
}
```

If I comment out a `TestConfiguration` then everything works fine.
Thank You in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set `MethodValidationPostProcessor#setProxyTargetClass(true)` because by default `MethodValidationPostProcessor` uses JDK proxy which leads to loss of your controller in the Spring context.

When `AbstractHandlerMethodMapping#processCandidateBean` is called `isHandler(Class<?> beanType)` will return `false` because JDK proxy doesn't contain `@RestController` annotation.

```java
  public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    MethodValidationPostProcessor mvProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    mvProcessor.setProxyTargetClass(true);
    return mvProcessor;
  }
```

Comment: Thank You, it works! But I would understand why do I need to set it but 2 similar examples from similar questions don't have it? Is it linked to JDK version? I'm using 14

Comment: I believe it doesn't depend on JDK. I can't quite answer your question because I didn't run these examples. It's possible that old Spring versions can work with JDK proxies. To check it need to take a look to the code that Spring version

Comment: Also, if you take a look comments under the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594623/spring-rest-controller-requestparam-validation) you will see that they had run into the same problem as you had. I guess https://github.com/wololock/rest-validation-demo wouldn't work without  `MethodValidationPostProcessor#setProxyTargetClass(true)`